# How can I add an automatic timer to an elevated Button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, button, timer, countdowntimer

I have a container in which the user is invited to click a button to start the NEXT PART of his test. The next part must however start automatically after 15 seconds even if he doesn't click the button.

Is there a way to add such a function to a button ?

Comment: could you add your code too?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TextButton(
child: Text('Send Again'),
style: TextButton.styleFrom(
  primary: Colors.teal,
  onPrimary: Colors.white,
  textStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 40,
      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
  ),
),
onPressed: () {
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 15), () {

// Here you can write your code

  print('Pressed');

});
 
},
```

)